# What is the +Subproject commit?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, gitlab

I want to clone an old project from gitlab. And when I cloned it to my computer, I found there are two folders which contain nothing. So I check the Commits from gitlab and there are info like:

```
Folder Name@xxxxxxx
+++ a/Folder Name
+Subproject commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Folder Name@xxxxxxx
+++ a/Folder Name
+Subproject commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And also I couldn't find the `.gitmodules` file, there is just a `.git` file.
[image: files in .git]

I have no idea about it. Anyone know how to load the code of the two "folders"?

Comment: The lack of a `.gitmodules` file doesn't stop Git from having and needing-to-use a submodule, it just stops Git from being able to provide the submodule automatically. Provide the missing `.gitmodules` or initialize the submodule manually.

Comment: @torek Then how can I initialize the `.gitmodules `file? Should I just create a foler named `.gitmodules`?

Comment: @Lynx You don't initializes it unless you have the URL of the remote repositories which have those folders content. If you don't know what repository was used fro those folders, then there is no submodule to restore.

Comment: The `.gitmodules` file is a file (not a folder), with special syntax, as understood by `git config -f .gitmodules`. You must create this file and place in it the correct information that allows Git to find the *other* Git repository or repositories. The best way to do that is to start with the correct collect of Git repositories and use `git submodule` to create the `.gitmodules` file, but it sounds like the correct content for the `.gitmodules` file is lost. Creating the correct content is nontrivial, unless you remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of:

```
git ls-tree HEAD folderxxx
```

If you see 160000, that means it is a special entry in the index representing the root folder of a [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) (check if you have a `.gitmodules`) or of a nested Git repository.

That would explain why you have an empty folder, since Git would not usually version a folder with no data (file) in it.

Comment: Yeah, there is a 160000. And there is not a `.gitmodules` but a `.git`. The pic above which i posted is the inside of the `.git` folder. So how can I do to get the code?

Comment: @Lynx You have to copy it from its source, because if there is no `.gitmodules`, Git alone would not know *where* to fetch the code from.